# How can I add a second shaded confidence interval (ie., a 95% and 85% CI) to a glm visualization using plot_model()?

Tags: r, data-visualization, ggplot2

Using `plot_model()`, I have visualized the marginal effects for several model terms (see figure below). The `plot_model()` function allows you to specify the confidence level and will automatically plot a shaded confidence interval.

I would like to plot a *second* confidence interval over the first one, so that both the 95% and 85% can be seen (in order to further demonstrate the strength of responses). Is this possible?

Here's some abbreviated dummy data that demonstrates my question:

```
response   per.grs
0          0.2430000
0          0.7142857
0          1.0000000
0          0.7619048
0          0.7619048
0          0.1230000
0          0.6666667
0          0.3560000
0          0.9523810
0          0.1450000
1          0.7619048
1          0.6432000
1          0.6666667
1          0.8571429
1          0.8571429
1          0.5238095
1          0.9523810
1          0.8450000
1          0.5714286
1          0.7619048
```

Here's the code I've used:

```
grass.cover <- glm(response ~ per.grs + I(per.grs^2), data=data, family=binomial, na.action = "na.fail")
plot_model(grass.cover, type = "eff", terms = "per.grs[all]", ci.lvl = .95)
```

[image]

Comment: Questions that are only about software (e.g. error messages, code or packages, etc.)
are generally off topic here. If you have a substantive machine learning or
statistical question, please edit to clarify.

Comment: @gung-ReinstateMonica Done. I've added some data that produces the figure in the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved like so. I had a look inside `plot_model`. The data for the plot is computed via `ggeffects::ggeffect`. So I simply compute the data also for the 85% which then can be used to add a second shaded area via `geom_ribbon`. However, as this also overplots the line with predictions we have to add a `geom_line` to get the predictions back into the plot. However, especially in case that you want to have a legend for both CIs I would recommend to make the whole plot yourself via `ggplot2`.(;

```r
data <- structure(list(response = c(
  0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L,
  0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
), per.grs = c(
  0.243,
  0.7142857, 1, 0.7619048, 0.7619048, 0.123, 0.6666667, 0.356,
  0.952381, 0.145, 0.7619048, 0.6432, 0.6666667, 0.8571429, 0.8571429,
  0.5238095, 0.952381, 0.845, 0.5714286, 0.7619048
)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(
  NA,
  -20L
))

grass.cover <- glm(response ~ per.grs + I(per.grs^2), data = data, family = binomial, na.action = "na.fail")

library(sjPlot)
#> Install package "strengejacke" from GitHub (`devtools::install_github("strengejacke/strengejacke")`) to load all sj-packages at once!
library(ggplot2)

p <- plot_model(grass.cover, type = "eff", terms = "per.grs[all]", ci.lvl = .95)

# Get data for 85% CI
dat85 <- ggeffects::ggeffect(model = grass.cover, terms = "per.grs[all]", ci.lvl = .85)

p +
  # Add 85% CI
  geom_ribbon(data = dat85, aes(x, ymin = conf.low, ymax = conf.high), fill = "grey") +
  # Get the predictions back (;)
  geom_line(data = dat85, aes(x, y = predicted), color = "black")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! I knew I somehow needed to extract the additional confidence interval but could not figure out the ggeffect part. This is very helpful